# ion-nav-back-button is not working with views with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying develop an app with ionic-framework and angularJS.

I have used $stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider for navigation among the view. I have **ion-nav-back-button** on the page, to navigate to previous view in the history.

This is my routing logic,

```
$stateProvider
      .state('sideMenu', {
          url: "/SideMenu",
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: "Templates/SideMenu.html",
          controller: 'homeCtrl'
      })
.state('sideMenu.relations', {
         cache: true,
         url: "/Relations/:id",
         views: {
             'contentView': {
                 templateUrl: "Templates/Relations.html",
                 controller: "relationCtrl"
             }
         }
     });
 //only required navigation is shown here
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/SideMenu/Suggestions");
```

My problem is, ion-nav-back-button works Okay for the view without parameters. But if I go ahead of the view having parameter, it won't come back on the view in the history. Instead it goes to default page.

For example, If go to next view from "Relation.html" view, which is having "id" as parameter, On next view I can see back-button. But If I click on that button it brings me to default page "Suggessions.html" instead of "Relation.html".

**EDIT**

```
$ionicHistory.goBack();
```

This code to go back using $ionicHistory is also not working. That means views with parameters not getting added to the History.

Can anyone suggest me, what should I do with views with parameter to be added in history?

Answer (score 0):

Put only ":id" in url param. Like this:

```
.state('sideMenu.relations', {
     cache: true,
     url: "/:id",
     views: {
         'contentView': {
             templateUrl: "Templates/Relations.html",
             controller: "relationCtrl"
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/

With custom inner markup and custom click action, using $ionicHistory:

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"
    ng-click="myGoBack()">
    <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

The controller code

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicHistory) {
  $scope.myGoBack = function() {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  };
}
```

Comment: Not working. With this code also going to last view without parameter. I think, view's with parameters not getting added to the history.

Comment: If user will click on back (soft button) then it will not pass the parameters